# Is there any difference in creating tables with these two different statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for noob question, I'm still learning. I have these table:

| user |
| --- |
| user_id (PK) |
| username |
| password |

| user_product |
| --- |
| user_product_id (PK) |
| FK_user_id (FK with the user table) |
| name |
| deleted_at |

Personally (from tutorial I followed) I would create these tables with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_product(
  user_product_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_user_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  deleted_at DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (FK_user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

But I generated sql code from a diagram with **MySqlWorkbench** and it generated this command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my-database`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my-database`.`user_product` (
  `user_product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_product_id`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`FK_user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FK_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `my-database`.`user` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Why does the second command specify the username as index instead of primary key? `UNIQUE INDEX username_UNIQUE (username ASC) VISIBLE`

Why does the second command set only the foreign key as index on the second table? `INDEX user_id_idx (FK_user_id ASC) VISIBLE`

Which one is better, the first command, or the second?

Comment: so the first is the short form for the latter, and they do the same and are the same, as you omit in the frist the default values for the statement.

Comment: It looks like you told Workbench that your `user.username` column is supposed to have unique values, so it generated a UNIQUE index. Other than that, what @nbk said: Workbench spelled out all the defaults, where your handcrafted code doesn't. Either form is fine and they are equivalent. The second one reminds somebody in the future (yourself or somebody else) about the defautls.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you for the reply, sorry, I forgot to put the UNIQUE on first query. I edited the post

Comment: @nbk Thank you for the reply. In my first query, will it set the username as index of first table and the foreign key as index of the second table?

Comment: the primary key is already indexed and unique, so it can be used without any other methods directly as reference(which doesn't need to be unique, if it is indexed and vice  versa)

Comment: @nbk ok thank you, for some reason I thought that it would not use the primary key as index but only the username (on the first table) and FK (on the second table). So the first table have PK and username as indexes and the second table have PK and FK as indexes?

Comment: an index would make queies faster if the use username (for the first) or  FK_user_id in a WHERE clause or ON clause(which surely will happen